# Trying to validate a function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, validation

For my html, I'm trying to validate a form with a postcode input.

But this input is not working (or not being recognized). For my postcode input, I want to text box to only accept numbers.

Postcode input:

```
var Postcode = document.forms["Rego"]["postcode"].value;
var e = Postcode;           
var code = e.keyCode; 
if (code > 47 && code < 58) || code == 40 || code == 41 || code == 43) {
    return true;
}
alert("Invalid Postcode. Please enter numbers only.");
    return false;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: from you provided source, `code` = `document.forms["Rego"]["postcode"].value.keyCode`. But actually, there are not `keyCode` from `value`

Answer (score 1):

To only accept numbers, you can use (for HTML5):

```
<input type="number" name="whatever">
```

Plus, if you want to validate it with js (doing so in browser is not recommended as anyone can modify your js file and push the contents to the server) or server code, here's some insight:
Try to convert the string passed to the server into a number. For example, in python you can do: `int(whatever)`. If the conversion fails, that means the string isn't a number.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In your condition if in line 4 after 58 why you close the ) ???

Answer (score 1):

You are doing quite a few things wrong. You are not setting an event handler, you are actually binding to the value in the input box. You have to first get the DOM element representing the text box, then bind an event handler to the DOM element. Try this:

```
var Postcode = document.getElementById('post');
Postcode.onclick = function(e) {
         console.log(e);     
    var code = e.keyCode; 
    if (code > 47 && code < 58 || code == 40 || code == 41 || code == 43) {
        return true;
    }
    alert("Invalid Postcode. Please enter numbers only.");
        e.preventDefault()
        return false;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S47gV/

Answer (score 0):

If you use [HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp) you can set this automatically.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="47" max="58">
```

Comment: It's not recommended to rely on `type='number'` as it can easily be changed by an attacker.

Comment: I agree. That is why you should always have your server check too. But to make it a better user experience you check in the UI too.

Answer (score 0):

By using below code textbox/inputbox allow only numeric value

```
$j('#inputbox_id').keydown(function (e) {

                    if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    } else {
                        var key = e.keyCode;
                        if (!((key == 8) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

and if you want to set length of textbox/input box then set "maxlength=5"

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found what you are doing wrong:

You are reading postcode value from input type and then comparing its keycode.

However‚ it may work only when your input has single number and when you type more characters in it your postcode variable becomes something for example 5436 and then when you use keycode function on this in wont work as expected.